# Is there an opposite of the angular `ngInit` directive?

Tags: angularjs

I have one element,which is shows/hides on ng-if condition.

```
 <div ng-if="level <= vm.receivedLevelsAmountToShow" 
      ng-init="addTimeLineComponentData(vm.item)" >
          <div>{{item.id}}</div>
 </div>
```

when `ng-if` condition `true` - elements creates and `ng-init` -starts.
is there way to use something opposite `ng-init`, when the element disappears? (i want to use some methods when element disappears) 
thanks in advance.

Comment: You might create a directive which would be keeping eye on $destroy event of element,, to fire destruction triggers

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this.

```
<div ng-if="level <= vm.receivedLevelsAmountToShow" 
      ng-init="addTimeLineComponentData(vm.item)" >
          <div>{{item.id}}</div>
 </div>
```

Just use the opposite condition in an another blank div so that the ng-hide event of the forst div will be the ng-show event of second div. Even though the second div exist, it doesnot have any content so that your UI will not be affected.

```
<div ng-if="level > vm.receivedLevelsAmountToShow" 
      ng-init="YourCustomAction(vm.item)" >
 </div>
```

or else you have to opt a watch to the scope variable and need to trigger the event when the value changes.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $log) {
    $scope.$watch('level', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue > vm.receivedLevelsAmountToShow) {
            vm.YourCustomAction();
        }
    });
});
```